# Notice: Array to string conversion in php7

Tags: php-7.3

Migrating from version 5.0 to version 7.3 of PHP.

Show message, "Notice: Array to string conversion in", when I assign a string to the attachment, within the TreeMenuXL.php file on line 4.
The code is:

```
$a="<input type='radio' name='nivel' value='1' >&nbsp;".__toHtml('NOMBREMENU', ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
$arglist = array('text', 'link', 'icon');
for ($i=0; $i<$3; $i++) {
   $this->$arglist[$i]=$a;
}
```

What is the correct syntax in version 7.3. for $this->$ arglist[$i]=$a;
Thanks for your help.

Comment: first why the  $3   do you mean `for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {`

Comment: thanks, I corrected it but the error still follows

Comment: can output the error

Comment: just show me the message "Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\TreeMenuXL.php on line 4"

Comment: are these the first lines of your TreeMenuXL.php file??

Comment: they are not the first lines, but they are the first lines of the class that is called